# Grails 3 Application or Plugin

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

If I'm looking at project source code (in Intellij) how can I tell whether the Grails source code I'm looking at is an Application or a Plugin?

I get it that the output of a Grails Application build is a WAR, and a JAR for a Plugin but I can't figure out how to tell the difference by looking at the source code.

Bonus question: If it is a multi-module project, how do I tell which module is the Application and which modules are the Plugins? Or am I missing some important concept here?

Comment: Main application have static void main(String[] args) in grails-app/init/project/Appication.groovy file, while plugin wont have that file.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins can be run as applications as well and will often have an `Application.groovy` file.  Plugins will have a `<pluginname>GrailsPlugin.groovy` file which sets up the plugin.  In grails 3, this is in `/src/main/groovy` file structure.